# Possible to use Cellular encryption data to validate Geolocation?

Tags: encryption, mobile, gsm

I need offline-verifiable, time stamped, GPS signals or its equivalent.

Since cellular protocols include time stamps, encryption keys and other data, perhaps it's possible to re-use this infrastructure to provide some degree of "signed location data".  I'm guessing that each tower or base station has a unique key, or emits a signed ID of some type.

Disregarding whats currently legal in the US/UK, what is theoretically possible?

What is the most practical /legal approach?

Comment: What is the problem you're actually trying to solve ? Is the user device's cooperation possible ? Or do you need to do this without their device knowing ?